# C# CreateDocumentType for non-PUBLIC

Tags: c#, doctype

I want to get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE SUPRMRT SYSTEM "suprmrt.dtd">
```

I have the following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocumentType docType = doc.CreateDocumentType("SUPRMRT", "SYSTEM", "suprmrt.dtd", null);
doc.AppendChild(docType);
doc.Save(Console.out);
```

This produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE SUPRMRT PUBLIC "SYSTEM" "suprmrt.dtd">
```

So my question is can I get a result where PUBLIC is replaced by SYSTEM?  Also, if I replace "SYSTEM" with null, I get a set of empty quotes.  Can I stop that from happening?

Comment: Check the answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it like this.

```
XmlDocumentType docType = doc.CreateDocumentType("SUPRMRT", null, "suprmrt.dtd", null);
```

Here is the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createdocumenttype(v=vs.110).aspx)

> publicId
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The public identifier of the document type or null. You can specify a
>   public URI and also a system identifier to identify the location of
>   the external DTD subset.

Comment: Fantastic!  I can't believe that I didn't try that combination.  Thank you!

Comment: @JerseyMike It happens to everybody. Sometimes you just need another opinion/look. Good luck with your project :)